# Filling Field2 to icorresponding values in Field1 of shapefile using Field Calculator of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, shapefile, field-calculator, python-parser

I have to give explanation in a new field of the existing field which contains abbreviation.

Example: Field "Geology" has values Q, Qs,N....(abbreviation), I have to give explanation of those in a new field "Geologic Age", where Q is Quaternary Sediments and Qs is Quaternary sand & dunes.. and it need to be done for more than 100 entries, so manual is practically time taking,

something like "IF[GLG]=Q;THEN[Geologic_Age]=Quaternary sediments"

Answer (score 2):

you can use such condition in a codeblock, with as many "elif" as you want

```
def fill(a):
    if a== "x":
        return "definitionx"
    elif a=="b":
        return "definitionb"
    else:
        return "other definition"
```

and launch (with Python parser)

```
fill(!yourfield!)
```

**but** in your case I think that the best method would be to create a look up table (a table with two columns, one for the code and one for the description, one line per code). Then use [**Join Field**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000) to transfer it.

Comment: I'll take note of this. It's corrected (Join field used to be ArcInfo only).